# Excel - VBA transpose a vector

Tags: vba, excel

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2iWN.jpg)

I wrote a sub routine which prints out a random number (from 0 to 100) in column, and next to that column printed out the numbers increasingly. The numbers in the second column should be printed out in a cell (which the user assigns) but the values have to be in one row.

Could anyone help me how can I transpose that vector?

Comment: Include your existing code in the question

Comment: The reason why I didn't copy my code is the code is hungarian.

Comment: That doesn't really matter  - likely we can still follow it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple without VBA. Copy the range you want to transpose, then right-click and Paste Special -> Transpose.

If you would like to do this in VBA, try:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: It's okay, but my task is to write a function which transpose that range.

Comment: I think I can't do this because I don't know the range (the user have to surrend the range and it's varying).

Comment: The total exercise is the following:

Write a kind of function which do numbers (between 0 and 100 giving by the user) decreasing , after that do that numbers in a vector. And with an opctional parameter have to surrend we would like to get a row vector or a column vector.

Comment: I would be really grateful if someone could help me. Firsly, I did a sub routine but I don't know how to do this exercise with a function.